# JMeter- extract 'id' variables from JSON response and save it in CSV file and use it in tear down thread

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, json-extract, post-processor

In my post request create a job whose response have only id as follow,

```
{"id":626}
```

And I want to save the id value which is 626 in a csv or any file and after my test complete I want use all these value from this file to check the status of the job in the `tear down` thread group.

how to complete this ?
I have following script but getting error,

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id.each { entry ->
    new File('result.csv') << entry.get('id') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

error details,

```
2021-01-15 12:13:05,699 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.get() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [id]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), next(), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), abs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `entry.get('id')` to just `entry` and it should work:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id.each { entry ->
    new File('result.csv') << entry << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

---

However there is a potential problem with your approach, if you run your script with > 1 thread you may run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when multiple threads will be concurrently writing into the same file so more error-proof approach would be:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=id
   ```
2. Extract the id from the response using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) configured like:

   [image]
3. Use [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to write the value(s) to the file:

   [image]

Comment: Dmitri, yeah the second option is more viable, one quick question suppose I have multiple step and and out of few are generating this job id individual each, then can be same file be used for the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, agree with Dmitri prefer the second option, and just the blow line should fix your issue.

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id.each { entry ->
    new File('result.csv') << entry << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Like Dmitri mentioned.