# Read id one by one in tear down and get the status

Tags: jmeter

Continuing from previous thread,
[JMeter- extract 'id' variables from JSON response and save it in CSV file and use it in tear down thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732172/jmeter-extract-id-variables-from-json-response-and-save-it-in-csv-file-and-us)

Able to write all the id from the various steps in to a files result.csv. Now I want to iterate through each id in the tear down thread to check the status of the job id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) inside `tearDown thread group`,

Set Infinite loop count in  `tearDown thread group`,

Mark in `CSV Data Set Config` Stop thread of EOF = true, Recycle on EOF = false

That way it will iterate against of ids saved and you can check for each the job id using the variable name you set in `CSV Data Set Config`

Answer (score 0):

Using interim file for passing data between thread groups is not the best idea, disk IO is horribly slow comparing to in-memory operations.

You could convert use JMeter Properties ([__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in 1st Thread Group and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the tearDown Thread Group) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) for this.

If you need to check the status against some anticipated value - go for [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), it has possibility to compare 2 JMeter Variables.

[image]