# Need to extract all the values found in the response for a particular ReGex

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing, post-processor

I have to extract all the contactIDs from the response using Jmeter. I am using the regex - **"contactId":"(.+?)",** but not able to figure out how we can extract all the contact IDS and save it in a file as it searches for particular match count.
I've tried with match count as "-1" as well but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how I can extract all the contact IDs and save in a file?

```
{"draw":2,"pageNumber":1,"recordsTotal":231,"recordsFiltered":231,"data":[{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a3602cfc472437a15ed@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"S3FWTmJ1MUNjMVRURXgzVU4rSHFNYW9vaDlrNVFHQ0t3VDBNUzBjSndrMGo0RFlGMExmeVZRMHFvcHZoNEIxZQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a369594baad2a260f05@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"OGRKVDZoT25HZldRUDRlQkZOdGw5c3h4RGE4YXlzQXpyUzF0eWlaeXlJUkdESHFydmdRd1ByQTZqYm5DbjZmSg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":0},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"6018157b45ab5f856221e363@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"WmdTeUtiUTg0dmd1dUpjL21Cbzk2c2dmMlNBb3RhU3FpNFlTTzhCQ0dlZkdWaUJpMVlpTm5GMG9mSytaWDhWNg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36825d5a669cf094dd@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"c3VHS3hYRjZ3WVhpbU1UOHF1bGtPNG0zOFp4SmZWdWdjTlpzYlltaGZLK04ySldNeFlrVnJaNVNRN3l0M0ljVg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a3694e28011418968a6@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"M2ZPdEFMTFNhMzFqYzhjaGt2b2hYZEl2d2kvWm5VYmtZTWRkSnZvL2xFMGtzUHpKQkpGT3VTQXJWaFR0M09KWg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36def11332d9add030@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"ZytuTzZwd293RUZpazh2aXZxQWRMcHdHeDBYT1UvaXJVdmswTHhCczZDZG1aZkRmOCtRdUgrNTlxWC9xaHIzRA==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a3638f5421ba23b7720@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"Z1M4Ni8ybGZVYURtZ3hZczJxZkhIT1E3L3NZYklYRXZJdmh1YngvSjhkTmJPd3hvcElDR05DckljeGZpeVkwNg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36c4854309c89fa17a@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"VUFOL0V6Q3lzWDZWTm9MRHRpSTFNRWJqYUNrQ2xobWZ0VWlRUExHT3p5dzh0YkFuMnBUNllScWFNTkQ5d3dwVQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a3680249a0711682b7f@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"MjBvN1JGRERaUDlqM1YrVHM0N0EzVzlGZVk5SHV4cnVSUXQzMjJzd0RqS0UxMUtqdXlibU45V0huRUNhRFFEbw==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a367f4c7d96a4d0ca9f@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"elMrRHdWNkFJTjlSdUhEY1A0d1FwN3JvS1E5MGVsSFZNTkNwSmVWL01Bcm90a3dXKzhMQU9SVjRoWFExUCtpdQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36d2210b1b5a7e47e0@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"OUxLM2FqUXZ4dWlGZVBGTjhiY0tOek03WW0wK1FMQ01IRzFCTmIrNU9hcFdUTWpTRFp6S3RIdmhWUm9tUDBNdQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a363c17c1f516a3cac7@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"a2MrclFCU2xGQ0haWWtDVWU4RFZGY2JJOWpKRkYrcDkwMStPVG1OMzgrQVZlQ3RPenVkdTRjTWsxdzAvbkt0aw==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a3638dfafef37f4c045@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"bG9SL2J0MTVIM3RIZUs4Y1pmbUtUVll1ZlNKdFJuS1JIc1V3TFRJb2hWN3hkVGVsSVpaNVl6TUlhb1ZLMWFRTg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a364f4edb7597d1ac7e@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"cVZSc1BBMEJtOTNhMGVrWVlZVGdPbU5Pc1ZCWTRLWUlDOUtvbDErQTVKbk11VE5rREcwenI5bnE0WW1pUSt0Lw==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36c0a34bc8eab03072@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"UGhPbHpmUG1OS0k0bDZMT25IS1lWNncrOTg0Q29vVG1yUnZVWFhicTFyTTBkdnU0bzdVUG5WVzlSMnpYV3VPag==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36d4adf0e1a61df7f2@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"cTVuQUtPd2tOQ0luN3ozUWQxbGZ5d25jRDRnN3Q5WjFSdlNlcEN1Y1Q4K0hETmhXM21ZbFpTMGNUSDBSNDlDdQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36d703522aad57cf4c@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"cVRZSU8yYmdlMnhQYWc5TEN1Mk1jV0hkM0kvT2FldXpKQUF0MHNGM0t4SGM1MG1zamwrVExCUkNQdUJsRUVlbQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36cd57aea0a235ff10@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"TVI3NFdNM3ludzJzTWd0bEhVemdJQ0xvUDFuUGpxcnlGejZlTFRESjd4L2tHRE0rbkpxbDJnUmlWek1wTlhuWQ==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a360eaaa04896b31a73@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"M3I0Qm53a0dTRW9kUkVIcnh4UWRaZHQrcDVMTUVTcEY1dTZYZFlrVFB6bkZjNlB5S29EYVNTQU5HMTBiOGwwbg==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""},{"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"60193a36edcf29f81b9b9129@tempmail.bondoya.com","status":"Unregistered","productsArray":[{"schemeIdSf":"d0dqVXd5b25wVFArWTFkc3l0dUV5SmhiZGs1ZC9UQXRtRGdQS3VHRTJjdWxXZUdWaXJjeXlBcm1rbWNMSUNjKw==","productName":"Healthy Living"}],"firstLogin":"","resendInvite":true,"isEmailVerified":"","canDeRegister":true,"products":"Healthy Living","contactId":"Q0dVVkhUMmdNbXgzNWFaY3hockg0QnY2cFFSN2ZNczZVR0xYd0cyMGpGZDBrSFR1Q2tlY0tYMm02YTh0KzY1SA==","pageNumber":1,"employeeReferenceNumber":"","deregisterInfo":{"reason":"","slug":"","date":""},"deregisterdate":""}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)
also check this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38110/how-to-extract-multiple-named-values-from-a-json-object-with-jmeter?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I am able to save all the contactIDs in Jmeter Variable (as ContactID_Encrypt_1, ContactID_Encrypt_2..) but I also have to save them in a file for future use.

Comment: Bhavya, I guess you can go with Dmitri suggestion or you can use `Flexi file writer` for writing these `id` to a file for future purpose.

Comment: Please refer this discussion, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732172/jmeter-extract-id-variables-from-json-response-and-save-it-in-csv-file-and-us`

Answer (score 0):

Your response seems to be JSON therefore it's better to consider using [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/), example configuration:

[image]

In order to write the values into a file you can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and use the following code:

```
1.upto(vars.get('ContactID_Encrypt_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    new File('ids.csv') << vars.get('ContactID_Encrypt_' + index) << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})
```