# "FlexiWriter" is not working in NonGui mode

Tags: jmeter

Have a script which add a `job_id` (parameter name) to a CSV file. This works fine in GUI mode but when I run it from command line it is adding `UNDEFINED_variable#0` what I have missed here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you missed the configuration at some place, please follow carefully @Dmitri instruction,

[JMeter- extract 'id' variables from JSON response and save it in CSV file and use it in tear down thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732172/jmeter-extract-id-variables-from-json-response-and-save-it-in-csv-file-and-us)

You must have missed the `user.properties` file configuration:

```
sample_variables=id
```

because, the error indicate this configuration miss

Comment: Yeah I was running two version of JMeter, in non gui mode I missed the configuration. Thanks